# Having issues trying to store values into a tuple in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

SOLVED: The text file had three rows at the end without value so it returned the error.

So I'm trying to store some values from a text file into a tuple and it worked at first but then I don't know what I changed that I doesn't run now.

The code I have is as follows:

```
processes = []
item = 1
asins = open("asins.txt", "r+")
contenido = asins.readlines()
asins.close()
for l in contenido[1:]:
    processes.append(l.split()[-1])
    while item < len(processes):
        print(str(item), processes[item])
        item = item + 1


print (processes)
```

The error it throws is this one:

> line 8, in 
> id_producto.append(i.split()[-1])
> IndexError: list index out of range

Thank you in advance

Comment: instead of splitting- print l.split() to see what it is and to get behind the error

Comment: Thank you for answering, that solved my problem. The text file had the last three rows with no values.